# Can't edit/copy files with Samba on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: openelec, samba

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 2 model B, and I installed OpenElec which seems to work as expected, with an external HD plugged in USB.
During the setup wizard I enabled Samba, and now I can connect via Finder (OS X 10.11 El Captain) with command `smb://192.168.0.10`... Once executed the command, I can login as guest or user (root-openelec), but both user type don't give me permission to edit/delete/add files. Whenever I try to do something, I'm asked to login, but then the previous user-password are not accepted anymore..

I went to see samba.conf file in `/usr/share/services/samba.conf` and it looks like this:

```
SAMBA_AUTOSHARE="true"
SAMBA_USERNAME="openelec"
SAMBA_PASSWORD="openelec"
SAMBA_SECURE="false"
```

but those user and pass don't work.

How could I transfer files between my mac and the HD plugged into the raspberry usb?

Comment: Who owns the samba directory and what are the permissions? can you also edit your question and add the entire smaba.conf file.

Comment: This is actualy the only samba.conf I have on my Rpi. I see there is another one named samba.conf.sample in `/storage/.config/`.

Comment: And what about the ownership and permissions? Also have you rebooted the Pi?

Comment: Yes, I have already rebooted the pi, and I was never asked for username or password when using OpenElec. I just saw, during setup, that user and password are root/openelec

Comment: You keep IGNORING the question of directory ownership and permissions!

Comment: A better solution would be to install `netatalk` on the Pi which will allow you to connect from your Mac using Finder over your LAN. Search this site for `netatalk` for more detail. `open afp://192.168.0.10` should give you access to the /home directory

Comment: Don't forget the samba `testparm` command - it will check whether your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file makes sense (is internally consistent) it won't fix the problems but anything it moans about is worth rechecking.

Comment: @SteveRobillard the HD folder owner is root, but any subfolder's owner is 99... I don't know what this means.
Permission on HD folder are `drwxrwxr-x`, while subfolder `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: @Milliways how can I install netatalk if I can't use apt-get?

Comment: @SlySven should I put it in samba.conf? I see it has various parameters, can you suggest what line should I add to samba.conf?

Comment: Are you sure you have samba.conf and not smb.conf - unless there was some change with Samba 4 I think the configuration file is the smb.conf one.  As for setting one up - it has been such a while since I *ran* a Windows PC and needed to get anything from a \*nix Box I'm probably out of date on many of the things needed. 8-(

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it by reformatting the HDD. From OS X I had to use Disk Utility with following setup:
Format: ExFat
Scheme: Master Boot Record

Now everything is working as expected. I hope this will help future coming newbie like me.

Comment: There were ways of handling this without nuking the contents of the disk, had you given us the info we asked for.